# How do I shorten this code to make the date SQL compatible?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using tkcalendar to get dates. The date format is `'DD/MM/YYYY'`. However, SQL DATE format accepts only `'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

I have the following code:

```
dated = cal.get_date()
dates = dated.split('/')
reverse_dates = dates[::-1]
    
separator = '-'
final_date = separator.join(reverse_dates)
print(final_date)
```

where, `cal` is a `tkcalendar.Calendar` object. Is there a shorter way to write this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `strftime`:

```py
date = cal.get_date()
date_str = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print("date formatted: ", date_str)
```

Using a value of `datetime.now()` for the starting date, the output from the above script is:

```
date formatted: 2020-11-23
```